# Проверить текст переменной одним regExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

как проверить одним  regExp содержимое текста из переменной text?
проверка имени и навыка на содержание только текста и выдать true/folse, а возраста на содержание только цифр и выдать true/folse.
учу JS и не понимаю как выполнить...
Спасибо всем кто поможет!

let text = "Name: Dima, Years: 25, skills: html"

Comment: В тексте может быть только основной латинский алфавит или буквы любого алфавита?

Comment: И могут ли там быть пробелы, тире, другие пунктуационные знаки?

Comment: `skills` подразумевает множественное число? Если да, то как разделены навыки между собой?

Comment: У вас же 'text' уже строка, как вы хотите проверить возраст/скиллы итд на другие типы, если все будут строкой. Может вы имели ввиду объект?

Comment: Наверное, подразумевалась не столько строгая проверка на типы, сколько проверка подстрок на вид содержимого — цифры, буквы и т.д.

Comment: Трудно что то комментировать с малым уровнем знаний. Могу сказать только что let text = "Name: Dima, Years: 25, skills: html" ,это конкретный текст который необходимо проверить одним regExp. В случае когда в имени или скилах будут только буквы и в возрасте только цифры то получить true. Если в имени и скилах появится цифра или в возрасте буква выдать folse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        let regexp = /^Name: \p{L}{2,}, Years: \d{1,3}, skills: (\p{L}{2,}\|?)+$/u;
        let string = 'Name: Dima, Years: 55, skills: js';
        let res = regexp.test(string);

        demo.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень неточное описание задания. Остаётся только предполагать. Если предположить:

1. Названия категорий будут идти всегда в данном порядке.
2. Категории разделены запятыми
3. Если навыков может быть много, и они разделены `|` (взял с потолка, но можно заменить на что-то своё).
   Регулярка примет примерно следующий вид:
   `^Name: \p{L}{2,}, Years: \d{1,3}, skills: (\p{L}{2,}\|?)+$`
   `\p` не работает без флага `u`.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное это то что мне нужно было, через некоторое время дам ответ. Описание задания... 
Пошел на курс что бы быстрее учиться, а в итоге только больше трачу время... Надеюсь иду правильной дорогой.